# passing a variable from a service to a broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Hello guys i am trying to send two variables from an android service to a broadcast receiver, and i need help here..

i am setting up two var's in the oncreate method of the service class here..

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();


    Intent eSendIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OutgoingCallReceiver.class);

    eSendIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("BlockArray", contactsListB);
    eSendIntent.putExtra("BlockBool", checkB);
    getApplicationContext().sendOrderedBroadcast(eSendIntent, null);//Call receiver



 }
```

and in my receiver class...

```
onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

            if(bundle == null)
                    return;


            boolean cb = bundle.getBooleanExtra("BlockBool", true);
            ArrayList<String> ab = bundle.getStringArrayListExtra("BlockArray");


//disconnecting
            try{

                if(cb==false){
                for(int ij = 0; ij < ab.size(); ij++){
                    if(ab.get(ij).contains(phonenumber)){

                        tempBoolean = true;
                        //Log.e("OutgoingCallReceiver", SmsBlockerService.contactsListB.get(ij));
                    }
                }//for loop
                    if(tempBoolean==true){

                setResultData(null);
                        Toast.makeText(context, phonenumber + " is Blocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

            }else{
                setResultData(null);

                Toast.makeText(context, "All Out-Going Calls are Blocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }//end of main if

                    } catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Detect Calls sample application Failed: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
}
```

logcat:

E/BroadcastReceiver(1459): BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast

Comment: And what happens next?

Comment: Your question is not complete

Comment: i am unable to receive any values

Comment: Is your receiver registered in AndroidManifest? Or is it a receiver created and registered in Activity?

Comment: check whether your intent is getting received in onReceive().. Check whether code inside onReceive is being called

Comment: in your code you have no `Log.d(TAG,"");` so it is normal that it doesn't show anything , you question is not well explained , ( and on the `onReceive` if you are waiting for the OutGoingCall to be catched, you should add the `IntentFilter` to your `BroadCastReceiver` declaration in the manifest , and when sending broadCast , you should specfify the Action that will be broadcasted to the receivers ,

Comment: yes i have registered my receiver with an intent filter in manifest now but still not working...and also added the log statement. the logs show false and 0, while it should be showing true and otherone should show array list size as 2.

Comment: use this : `Intent sSendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
sendBroadcast(sSendIntent);`

Comment: can some body explain the use of sendBroadcast method, as i am experiencing error in my receiver class. and i updated my question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you registered the receiver.Now try to make a small change:

```
        boolean cb = bundle.getBooleanExtra("BlockBool", true);
        ArrayList<String> ab = bundle.getStringArrayListExtra("BlockArray");
```

Update:

In the on create... call the broadcast like...

```
  sendOrderedBroadcast(eSendIntent);
```

You are facing that error because , setResultData() function works only with OrderedBroadcast.

From Android Documentation:

```
   public final void setResultCode (int code)

   Added in API level 1
   Change the current result code of this broadcast; only works with broadcasts sent
   through Context.sendOrderedBroadcast. Often uses the Activity RESULT_CANCELED and  
   RESULT_OK constants, though the actual meaning of this value is ultimately up to the
   broadcaster.

   This method does not work with non-ordered broadcasts such as those sent with 
   Context.sendBroadcast.
```

Comment: If it works.. dont forget to up vote or tick the answer @Ajax-theMax :)

Comment: i tried sending an int variable just to check and it worked. so now my main problem is from sharedpreferences. the two var's i am trying to retreive from sharedpreferences is the main culprit.

Comment: Where did sharedPreference come here.. anyways...it works right...if not.. then explain your where you are facing the problem in detail.

Comment: shared prefs problem is solved, now i am getting another error in receiver, check my updated question.

Comment: Try using an ordered broadcast instead of normal broadcast.

Comment: Check this tutorial @Ajax-theMax.. [OrderedBroadcast](http://blog.truiton.com/2013/04/android-sendorderedbroadcast-example-with-priority/)

Comment: yes changed to ordered broad cast, but my outgoing call are not blocked...doesnt seem to effect i mean no errors too..?

Answer (score 1):

set this in your broadcast intent

```
         i.setAction("MYACTION");
```

than set this in your manifest

```
   <receiver android:name=".BroadcastClass" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MYACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

may be this should helpful

Comment: applied your suggestion but not working, any more that i can do

Comment: first check by sending simple string or message if that call your broadcast than mistake is else where

Answer (score 0):

for broadcast receiver to work the activity/screen in which it is written should be up & running. so that receiver can receives the passed intent & it's value.

Comment: Also check whether you have register a receiver in AndroidManifest.xml file or in activity in which you are using receiver.